# About EM Lagrangian: Should electric flux density $D$ be a canonical conjugate variable of electric field $E$?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, polarization

Recently I've reviewed classical Electromagnetism to understand D-brane more deeply, and I find I don't understand basic at all.

My book explains what is the action of electromagnetic field. To be general, we start with this (generalized) Maxwell's equations:

\begin{align*}
&\mathrm{div}D = \rho \\
&\mathrm{rot}H = j + \frac{\partial D}{\partial t}\\
&\mathrm{div}B = \rho_m \\
&\mathrm{rot}E = -j_m -  \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}
\end{align*}

First, we assume there are no charges: $\rho, \rho_m, j, j_m=0$.

The book says we should choose 2 independent variables of 4 ($D, H, B, E$) to construct action.
However, the Maxwell's equations don't tell us how $D, E (\textrm{or} B)$ or $H, B (\textrm{or} E)$ are related so I think I can't say these 4 is not independent in general.

This is my first question.

Of course, with some assumptions we introduce relations like $D = \epsilon E$, but **in general how we conclude that these 4 variables aren't independent?**

By the way, the book chooses $E, B$ as 2 independent dynamical variables. That's OK, but it says "Then, $D$ and $H$ become canonical conjugates of $E, B$: $D = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial E}, H = - \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial B}$".

How this is derived? This is my main question.

Assuming we only know above Maxwell's equation, then **can we say $D$ and $H$ become canonical conjugates of $E, B$** if we would like to construct the action and choose $E, B$ as 2 dynamical variables?

I think this is very basic question, sorry.

Comment: I've never seen $D$ described as the canonical conjugate of $E$... what book is this?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356856/2451

Comment: Related : [Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34241/).